# Python remove . after state

Tags: python, regex, str-replace

I have sentences with state codes followed by a . (ie. "CA.", "AL.", but also good "CA", "AL") or things like "acct." or "no."
I'd like to:
1. remove those "." 
2. keep other "."
3. change no. to #

For example, I'd like:
"Mr. J. Edgar Hoover from CA. owes us $123.45 from acct. no. 98765."
to become
"Mr. J. Edgar Hoover from CA owes us $123.45 from acct # 98765."

Changing " no."  to " #" 
         and "acct." to "acct" 
is easily done with regex or replace and I could do that first to get those out of the way. (I'm open to other efficient approaches).

But how do I change state code . to state code and keep the right state code?

Thanks!

Comment: I see what you are trying to do, but consider this sentence: `Mr. J. Edgar Hoover lives in CA.`: there's no way to know if the last dot is an abbreviation dot or a dot that ends the sentence.

Comment: I disagree. I think regex can do it: `re.sub('([A-Z]){2}.', '\1', line)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yup. Essentially, then, it turns into a question of disambiguating sentence endings from abbreviations. This is essentially what sentence tokenizers do. So one option is to use a sentence tokenizer, and then strip from the word tokens inside. Of course, this isn't going to work 100% of the time

Comment: There are lots of NLP packages out there, I think the current code writing request can be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

state code always contains 2 uppercase characters, so you can use this pattern to do your replacement.

match this: 
`([A-Z]{2}).`

and replace by this: `$1`

Comment: Thank you @coldspeed.       import re
test1 = "Mr. J. Edgar Hoover from CA. owes us $123.45 from acct. no. 98765."
fix1 = re.sub(r'([A-Z]{2}).', r'\1', test1)
fix1